# How can I know the size of a file using a recursive program?

Tags: python, operating-system

I have to make a program that measures the size of a given directory by using recursivity. I need to use the OS module. When I used

```
os.path.getsize()
```

The response was **0 byte**s, which makes no sense.

Comment: You'll need to post code for us to help. Recursion..., are you interesting in sizes of the entire subtree? `os.walk` works without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the path in the argument of a getsize function.
So it would look like:

```
os.path.getsize(<path_of_file>)
```

If you are doing that already and interested in the size of a folder, you can add size of the files in the folder iteratively.

```
sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir(<path_of_the_folder>) if os.path.isfile(f))
```

Comment: I now have this:     def sdir_files_size(Ruta):
    archivos = os.listdir(Ruta)
    if os.path.isdir(Ruta):
        return get_size(archivos)
    else:
        return 'Error: la entrada no es un directorio'

 
def get_size(archivos):
    if archivos == []:
        return []
    else:
        return os.path.getsize(archivos[0]) + get_size(archivos[1:])   #But i am getting an error which says: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Comment: You need to provide a string as a file path. For example, os.path.getsize("Documents/")

Answer (score -1):

I get your question, the same problem i also got, you can visit here for ans : https://github.com/ASHWIN990/sizeof/blob/master/sizeof

**I have made a Pythton script which find the size of file and directories recurcively**